# Input placeholder text not displaying under responsive mode in WordPress search field

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, input

I have the following search code. The text `Have a Question? Write here and press enter` doesn't appear under responsive mode.

```
 <div class="input-group" id="suggest">
            <input name="s" id="s" type="text" onKeyUp="suggest(this.value);" onBlur="fill();" class="search-query form-control pull-right" autocomplete="off" placeholder="'.esc_attr__('Have a Question? Write here and press enter','mywiki').'" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="">
            <div class="suggestionsbox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"> <img src="'.esc_url(get_template_directory_uri().'/img/arrow1.png').'" height="18" width="27" class="upArrow" alt="upArrow" />
              <div class="suggestionlist" id="suggestionslist"></div>
            </div>        
        </div>
```

I suspect it has something to do with `id="s"` in the input because if I change it to `id="sh"` the placeholder text appears.

So my question is why not `id="s"` and I prefer to use this cos it seems to be a WordPress default. I hate to fix it here and break something else somewhere.

UPDATE: I realized the issue with the original theme that I'm using -> https://fasterthemes.com/demo/mywiki-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by CSS code of, for example, your theme or that the color is the same as the input field background color.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The color is the same as the background.